# React Navigation always takes me to the first stack screen, not the intended screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Code 1(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Fkn.png)Code 2(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJBog.png)Code 3(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjV5.png)

So I have this issue where when I press a button (Receipt history button on the profile page for example), instead of it taking me to the receipt history page, it takes me to the login page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe no matter what link i set, whether it be "navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')" or "navigation.navigate('ReceiptHistoryScreen')" it always goes to the first item listed in the navigation. I have played around and changed what the first item is and it always goes to that.

For example:

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ReceiptHistoryScreen" component={ReceiptHistoryScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="LoginSuccess" component={LoginSuccess} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ReceiptDetailScreen" component={ReceiptDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

to

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="LoginSuccess" component={LoginSuccess} />
    <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ReceiptHistoryScreen" component={ReceiptHistoryScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ReceiptDetailScreen" component={ReceiptDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

the navigate that i set will now go to loginsuccess

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

try that with initialRouteName. Without giving initialRouteName  the default behavior is often to display the first route defined in the navigation configuration.   For example,

```
<NavigationContainer>
   <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={loggedin===true?'Home':'Login'} >
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me the issue you're encountering is caused by the order of the screens within the Stack.Navigator. When you press a button that triggers navigation.navigate('ReceiptHistoryScreen'), React Navigation will look for the first screen in the stack named ReceiptHistoryScreen and navigate to it. Since LoginScreen is the first screen in the stack, React Navigation is navigating to that screen instead of ReceiptHistoryScreen.

try this and let me know if this helps

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="ReceiptHistoryScreen" component={ReceiptHistoryScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginSuccess" component={LoginSuccess} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ReceiptDetailScreen" component={ReceiptDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```